# DOMException: Could not start video source | only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, camera, getusermedia, domexception

I am trying to get a video from my webcam. My code is working in Firefox and Microsoft Edge perfectly but not working in Chrome. I also host my code on an HTTPS server but didn't work.

My Code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
        .then( stream => console.log("success") )
        .catch( err => console.log(err, err.name) );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After running this code on Google Chrome browser, I am getting this error in the console:

```
DOMException: Could not start video source 'NotReadableError'
```

> Chrome Version: 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows
> 11.

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: I am getting this error in the console `DOMException: Could not start video source`

Answer (score 0):

this error appears if the camera is already in use by another browser or application